# how to send a image from a file in discordpy

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I'm trying to send a image from a folder in discord.py. I cant figure it out.
This is what i have so far...

````
async def neko(ctx):
    neko =[]

    for x in os.listdir("neko"):
        neko.append(x)


    await ctx.send(random.choice(neko))```

It sends the filename but it does not send the actual image.
````

Comment: How do you expect it to send the actual image?

Comment: Ive added discord.File to it but at that point it will give an error. 
"raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'neko548.jpeg'"

Comment: Is the image in the folder?

Comment: Well yes otherwise it wouldnt be sending the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You are not exactly getting the image. Try the code below, if it doesn't work you can always use the `PIL` package

```py
async def neko(ctx):
    neko_list =[]

    for x in os.listdir("neko"):
        neko_list.append(x)

    neko = random.choice(neko_list)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(neko))
```

Comment: I still get this error
"    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'neko092.jpeg'"

Comment: @LightFlavored Remember, you can always use PIL.

Comment: I would. but im not quite sure how it works. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Is your `neko092.jpg` file in the same directory as the python file? Or is it in an `image` folder?

Comment: It is in its own folder yes.

Comment: @LightFlavored provide a path to the image in place of the variable `neko` such as `/images/neko1.jpg`